# Autosave form fields for every 15 sec in AgularJS without using $watch

Tags: angularjs

I want to save a form field values every 15 sec with out using $watch and also it should stop executing once it has been moved  to a different form. In the form I will be having many fields so I think $ watch will be having performance issue and also am not sure how to call all fields at once for %watch. So I decided to use $interval but I want to stop this execution once I moved to different controller or different form. If user comes back again to this form again this interval function should start automatically. please would you suggest me best way to handle this.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Use $interval like you are planning to do but assign it to a variable

with $scope.on('$destroy', function() { }); callback you can destroy the interval when switching to a different controller.

```
var intervalPromise = $interval(function() { // your code }, 15000);
$scope.$on('$destroy',function(){
    if(intervalPromise)
        $interval.cancel(intervalPromise);   
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. I have tried below code, but unable to access other saveProductData whiich is in different controller. In my base controller I have written like below:
 var intervalPromise = $interval(function() {      
      if($scope.isInValidData()){  
   $rootScope.$broadcast('saveProductData',true);
  }
   
    }, 15000);
    $scope.$on('$destroy',function(){        
        if(intervalPromise)
            $interval.cancel(intervalPromise);   
    });

Comment: below is the correct code.
 var intervalPromise = $interval(function() {      
      if($scope.isInValidData()){  
   $rootScope.$broadcast('saveProductData');
  }
   
    }, 15000);
    $scope.$on('$destroy',function(){        
        if(intervalPromise)
            $interval.cancel(intervalPromise);   
    });
and in my 2nd controller I have saveProductData function.
 $scope.$on('saveProductData',function(){       
        $scope.saveProductData();        
    })